# Sending files over winsock/linux sockets

Tags: c

Hey, im making a simple program that sends/receives files, my code sends text files but when it comes to binary it starts to bug, code:

```
static void
send_event(conn,file)
  void *conn;
  void *file;
{
   FILE *f;
   char *buffer;
   int32_t block_size;
   int32_t size;
   size_t __read;
   ConnectionQueue *q;
   f = (FILE *)file;
   q = (ConnectionQueue *)conn;
   block_size = conf_getint("transfer:block_size");
   if (block_size <= 1 || block_size > 1024)
     {
       abort();
       return;
     }
   buffer = (char *)MyMalloc(block_size);
   if (!q || !f)
     return;

   fseek(f,0L,SEEK_END);
   size = ftell(f);
   if (size == 0L)
     {
       send_socket(q->conn,"RECEIVE: 302 FSE");
       return;
    }
   fseek(f,0,SEEK_SET);
   while (true)
    {
      if (q->abort)
       {
         send_socket(q->conn,"RECEIVE: File transfer aborted\n");
         if (f)
           fclose(f);
         f = NULL;
         MyFree(buffer);
         return;
       }
      __sleep(100);
       __read = fread(buffer,sizeof(char),512,f);
       if (__read <= 0)
         {
           send_socket(q->conn,"RECEIVE: EOF\n");
           break;
         }
      if (*buffer == '\0')
        {
          send_socket(q->conn,"RECEIVE: EOF\n");
          break;
        }

      send_socket(q->conn,"RECEIVE: %s\n",buffer);
   }
   send_socket(q->conn,"RECEIVE: 915 EOF\n");
   fclose(f);
   f = NULL;
   MyFree(buffer);
}
```

FIXED: Please check my answer \/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this fixed it -> [Send binary file in HTTP response using C sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496200/send-binary-file-in-http-response-using-c-sockets)

Answer (score 2):

What's with the K&R syntax and the `void *` parameters?

```
static void send_event( ConnectionQueue * conn, FILE * file) {
....
```

On binary vs text, typically this is because you open a file using "r" and not "rb" as mode.

```
 __read = fread(buffer,sizeof(char),512,f);
```

You should use `block_size` and not `512` there.

```
if (*buffer == '\0')
...
send_socket(q->conn,"RECEIVE: %s\n",buffer);
```

Your "binary files" could contain 0's - that's not a good EOF marker, and if you're using `strlen` in `send_socket` you'll get your data cut off at the first 0 in your buffer.

Comment: Thanks, please check out my answer, its all good now, ive voted you up, though