# How to send a file with http with c++

Tags: c++, http, download

I want to write a server side code. It should work with popular browsers and wget. My server check that file exists or not, if exists then browser can download it. But I have some problems.
Honestly, I read lots of question-answer (for example: [Send binary file in HTTP response using C sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496200/send-binary-file-in-http-response-using-c-sockets)) but I didn't find out. My browser (Chrome) can get text. But I cannot send any binary data or images etc. I am changing header according to downloading files. But I cannot send a downloadable files yet.

I have some questions.

```
void *clientWorker(void * acceptSocket) {
     int newSocket = (int) acceptSocket;
     char okStatus[] = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
                       "Content-Type: text/html\r\n"
                       "Connection: close\r\n"
                       "Content-Length: 20\r\n"
                       "\r\n"
                       "s";
     writeLn(newSocket, okStatus);
     const char * fileName = "/home/tyra/Desktop/example.txt";
     sendF(newSocket, fileName);
}
```

**1-** If I wouldn't write "s" or something else in`okStatus`, my message cannot send. I don't understand anything of this.

This is `writeLn` function :

```
void writeLn(int acceptSocket, const char * buffer) {
    int n = write(acceptSocket, buffer, strlen(buffer) - 1);
    if (n < 0) {
        error("Error while writing");
    }
}
```

This is `sendF` function :

```
string buffer;
string line;
ifstream myfile(fileName);
struct stat filestatus;
stat(fileName, &filestatus);
int fsize = filestatus.st_size;
if (myfile.is_open()) {
    while (myfile.good()) {
        getline(myfile, line);
        buffer.append(line);
    }
    cout << buffer << endl;
}
writeLn(acceptSocket, buffer.c_str());
cout << fsize << " bytes\n";
```

A little messy. I haven't used file size yet. If I send a file, then I rearrange these things.

**2-** I can send text and browser demonstrates it but browser didn't understand new lines.
If text file contains (123\n456\n789), browser demonstrates (123456789). I think I should change Content-Type header, but I didn't find out.

I don't want that browser demonstrates text files. Browser should download it. How can I send downloadable files?

Sorry, I explain everything pretty complicated.

Comment: I think one of the problems is that `okStatus[]` has no zero-termination char at the end.  Try adding it to the end, instead of 's'

Comment: @Tony The Tiger Thanks for helping. I tried and it didn't work.

Comment: @Tony The Tiger  Literal strings are automatically null-terminated

Comment: I don't know if its relevant, but the `Connection: close` part of `okStatus` is only followed only by a `\n`. It should be followed by `\r\n`.

Comment: @Andy, hmmm I wasn't entirely sure.

Comment: It works with this form but I changed it with \r\n in order to avoid complicacy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As to your first question, you should find out the exact size of the file and specify it in your `"Content-Length: xxxx\r\n"` header. And, of course, you should ensure that the data is sent completely out.

Indeed, in your `writeF` function you use a `std::string` as a buffer:

```
string buffer;
```

this is not appropriate for binary data. You should allocate a raw `char` array of the right size:

```
int fsize = file.tellg();
char* buffer = new char[fsize];
file.seekg (0, ios::beg);
file.read (buffer, size);
file.close();
```

As to the second point, when your data is not HTML, specify as Content-Type: `text/plain`;
otherwise, your carriage return should be represented by `<br>` instead of "\r\n".

In case of binary downloads, to have the data download as a file (and not shown in the browser), you should specify

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

Comment: Hello sergio. If I send binary data, chrome or firefox automatically download it?

Comment: Hello Thorn, see my edit. You need the `Content-Type: application/octet-stream`

Comment: Can I send rar file or something else with the same method (getline())  by changing only Content-Type?

Comment: Thorn, sure you can send rar files. Anyway, the getline approach is not the best. See my edit for code snippet specific to binary data.

Comment: If I want to send a downloadable file, I should send it in binary form, am I right? In this way, we can obtain a file which is identical with on the server? (not losing '\n')

Answer (score 1):

The issue is `strlen` here. `strlen` terminates when it gets a '\0' character. In binary file you will have a number of '\0' characters.

While reading the file you should find out the file size. This size should be used in `int n = write(acceptSocket, buffer, strlen(buffer) - 1);` in place of `strlen`

Change the `writeLn(acceptSocket, buffer.c_str());` to `writeLn(acceptSocket, buffer.c_str(), buffer.size());` and try...

For the case of `123\n456\n789` you need to send `<PRE>123\n456\n789</PRE>` as browser will parse this text as html and not like the OS parses and shows the output. The other way you can do is replace all `\n` with `<BR>` ...

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the answer. My first question is solved by your helping. I changed it and it works. About my second question, I do not want to demonstrate the text, browser should download it. I think I should change Content-Type and I send it right way (not getline), I do not know.

Comment: @Thom If the browser is able to parse mime "text/html" it's very likely that he'll do that as it is more convenient. But there is a way around: use the headers to indicate you want a download with `Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="test.jpg"`. See http://apptools.com/phptools/force-download.php for more details. It's php but the main http concepts still apply.

Comment: I'm not sure if I got it. I assume that you want your text file to be downloaded not displayed on the browser. In that case as @RedX suggested you need to use `Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="test.txt".`

Comment: @Thorn: You can have a look at this article [Content-Type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Type). Its a nice read

Comment: @RedX Thank you for advice. It works. Your link is very helpful. @Mayank Exactly:)

Comment: @Mayank, If I replace all \n with <BR> then downloaded file contains it. Same as <PRE>. In order to obtain identical file, should I send it binary?

Comment: @Thorn: `Replacing \n with <BR> or using <PRE>` was answer to the question when I thought its needed to be displayed in web-browser and not downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding question 1 - if you don't want to send any content back then remove the `s` from the end of `okStatus` and specify `Content-Length: 0\r\n` in the header