# How do I write images through HTTP in C?

Tags: c, http, networking, network-programming

Just now I have no problem for writing the HTML content through a connection.

```
    sprintf(toreturn, "%s\r\n%s\r\n%s\r\n\r\n%s", "HTTP/1.1 200 OK", "Content-Type: text/html", "Connection: close",htmlstring);
    write(*inputfd, toreturn, strlen(toreturn))
```

Which works fine. But this is what I am trying to pass an image in reply to an image request. In this case it is for `.ico` files, but my problem stands for any binary file.

```
    FILE *writefile = (FILE *)calloc(1,sizeof(FILE));
    char *charptr = inputaddress;
    charptr++;
    writefile=fopen(charptr,"r");

    sprintf(toreturn, "%s\r\n%s\r\n%s\r\n\r\n", "HTTP/1.1 200 OK", "Content-Type: image/vnd.microsoft.icon", "Connection: close");
    write(*inputfd, toreturn, strlen(toreturn))
    write(*inputfd, *writefile, strlen(toreturn)
    close(*inputfd);
    fclose (writefile);
```

Which doesn't work. How do I `write()` a image (or any binary file) file through HTTP in C?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496200/send-binary-file-in-http-response-using-c-sockets

Comment: You do not need this `FILE *writefile = (FILE *)calloc(1,sizeof(FILE));` - `FILE *writefile` will suffice.

Comment: The `calloc` is, sadly, the least of his problems...

Comment: Yep I would recommend he look at [sendfile](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sendfile) but he has way more problems than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use C string functions when working with binary data. C strings are terminated by 0-bytes, so using `strlen()` on any string that may contain binary data will return a truncated result.

Further, you can't use the `'*'` operator to get at the contents of a file. Also you shouldn't mix the `FILE*` functions (fopen/fclose/fread/fwrite) with the regular functions (open/close/read/write), and using `sprintf()` is generally asking for trouble - the safer replacement for that is `snprintf()`.

As for what you'll have to do to get it working, you should `open()` the icon for reading and then use the `read()` function to obtain data for your buffer in a loop until that returns a value less than 0. An example for that might be found here: http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=569

Comment: That was my first impression too. But if you look carefully he is not using the strlen function on binary data.  It is being used on a HTTP header string.  This is correct for the first call, but not for the second.

Comment: @Vlad ah yes, you're right, I'd somehow read it as him appending the binary data in the `sprintf()` call and got stuck with the other details there. Thanks for summing up all the other problems in your answer :D.

Answer (score 3):

Two problems:

1. You have to output the content length header in your HTTP header.
2. Writefile is not the data of your image, what your code does is simply outputs the content of file descriptor to the client.

The correct sequence should be like this

1. Open the icon file.
2. Query the length of the icon file
3. Create your HTTP header, the same way you do now but include the Content-Length header as well.
4. Read the contents of the file into a buffer
5. Output the contetns into the output socket.

Note, for large files step 4 and 5 have to be written in the loop otherwise you will be wasting memory.

Comment: Magnus has a good point that using the low level functions is better for the task at hand.  Furthermore,  linux has a low level kernel function 'sendfile'   http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sendfile.2.html   which will be more efficient for this task.  I think Windows environment has something similar.

Comment: Just a side note: I think the Content-Length header is still technically optional in HTTP/1.1 (or lower). At least if you close the connection right after sending the file. It's still a bad idea not to include it, of course. It might also be a good idea to write an HTTP/1.0 or HTTP/0.9 prelude for the message instead of HTTP/1.1, as that requires quite a lot more metadata to be supported by the server.

Answer (score 0):

So, what do you think *this* code does?

```
writefile=fopen(charptr,"r");
...
write(*inputfd, *writefile, strlen(toreturn)
```

If you said "write the contents of the file that `writefile` refers to to `inputfd`" you'd be wrong.

`write` takes a *buffer* containing the *actual* data you want to write, and requires that you specify how many bytes to write. You are passing it a `FILE` (which is not what the function expects or needs) and asking it to write as many bytes as your header.

Frankly, I'm surprised that this even compiles...

Try opening the file you want, finding out the size, allocating an appropriately sized buffer, reading the contents into said buffer, closing the file and then sending the entire buffer to the client.

Comment: Who modded it down?  This is actually a legitimate comment.